# Can an app track phone location?

Tags: android, geolocation

We have a mobile app planned, it needs to know it's location as a requirement to do it's job (in one incarnation). The location has to be withing 3-5m (10-16ft) accuracy and has to be updated every 30s to 1min.

1. Is it possible to do?
2. Would it be a resource hog on the battery or hardware?
3. What about the permissions to check or gather this kind of data?

Comment: This should answer all your questions: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/index.html

Comment: 1. yes, 2. yes, 3. GPS permissions

Answer (score 0):

For balanced location services you should use [Google fused location Api.](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi)

Fused Location Api has options of balanced power mode and high accuracy mode. TBH, its not that of resource hog.

Permissions required:`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`